# How to cut the date out of a string in Shell?

Tags: string, shell, sed, filtering

I got a list of Strings like this in a .txt file

```
asdafdgdhjhgk.de/dsafdfdfgfdggfgg - Abgelaufen seit 26.11.2076 14:08 (seit 12345 Tagen)
```

Now I want to cut the date out of the strings like: `26.11.2076`

All this have to happen in a Shell-Script so I through `cut` or `sed` would be a good idea but i didn't found an answer in the internet.

Comment: What did you try? did you find similar question on the site? I am sure you can find quite a few of them here.

Comment: (and) You want to extract the date(s) from a file or a single instance of the above string only?

Comment: If the Date is always in the same field, you could use awk to extract the field.  `$ echo 'asdafdgdhjhgk.de/dsafdfdfgfdggfgg - Abgelaufen seit 26.11.2076 14:08 (seit 12345 Tagen)' | awk '{print $5}'`

Comment: It's hard to infer a common format that is "like this" from a sample of 1. Post a FEW lines of input and the associated expected output and what you have tried so far, see [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GNU grep` with `-E` with extended `regEx` support using the `-E, --extended-regexp` flag.

```
$ grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{4}" <<< "asdafdgdhjhgk.de/dsafdfdfgfdggfgg - Abgelaufen seit 26.11.2076 14:08 (seit 12345 Tagen)"
26.11.2076
```

(or) if you want to run it on a file with multiple such strings, do

```
$ grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{4}" input-file
```

Comment: wouldn't this also allow `32:13:2016` to print ?

Comment: @PS. Fair enough! OP has just asked for extraction? and not a well formatted extraction. It is understood that he has date formatted properly in his input file

Comment: The OP hasn't told us what he wants yet but that would match on 0123456789 and other things that certainly aren't what the OP wants (hint: `.` is a RE metacharacter). I didn't downvote it either btw, just sayin'...

Answer (score 2):

If the structure of the logs/lines are similar from start till the date then following could be used:

```
awk '{print $5}' input
```

Or

```
grep -oP '([3][0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[0][1-9])\.([0][0-9]|[1][0-2])\.[0-9]{4}' input
```

*Note: this may break for month of feb.*

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to text parsing, I almost always prefer Perl.

Multiple comma-separated matches per line:

```
perl -ne '@_=/((?:\d\d\.){2}\d{4})/g and print join(",", @_), "\n"' file
```

Multiple matches per line joined into a single column:

```
perl -ne 'while (/((?:\d\d\.){2}\d{4})/g) {print "$&\n";}' file
```

The first matches:

```
perl -ne '/((?:\d\d\.){2}\d{4})/ and print "$1\n"' file
```

If the dates are followed by time, add `(?: \d\d:\d\d)` to the regular expressions, e.g.

```
/((?:\d\d\.){2}\d{4})(?: \d\d:\d\d)/
```

This will make the matches stricter. Note, `(?:)` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap).

I also like `grep`'s `-P` option that enables Perl-compatible regular expressions:

```
grep -o -P '(?:\d\d\.){2}\d{4}' file
```

But some implementations may not support it:

> This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.

(the man page for `grep`).